# SQL statement to return values older than x months

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, string, datetime

What I'm trying to do here is create a sql statement to go after some WHERE conditions, this statement is $build. What I'm attempting to do here is take the integer $age which is a value in months, and then I want the statement to make it so that only results older than $age months are returned in my sql statement. The column datetime contains the age of the row in the table, screenshot of the column

[image]

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE type='plugin' and access_restriction<'$permissions'";

if ($age!=""){
    $time = date('H:i:s', time());
    $years = date('Y');
    $months = date('m');
    $days = date('d');
    $newmonths = $months - $age;

    while ($newmonths <=0) {
        $years = $years - 1;
        $newmonths = $newmonths +12;
    }
    $age = $years . "/" . $months . "/" . $days . " " . $time;
    $build = $build . " and datetime<CAST('" . $age . "' AS DATE)";
}

$sql = $sql . $build;
```

I included $sql at the beginning and $sql . $build at the end so you can see how they fit together

Thanks for any help, If I've worded something badly or you don't understand please comment.

Note, if $age = 0; initially it returns the values

Comment: Please edit your post with the value of `$sql`.

Comment: Print $sql and please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the date 5 months in the past you can do this:

```
$howManyMonthsBack = 5;
$dateAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), date('m') - $howManyMonthsBack , date('d'), date('Y')));
```

and then in mysql you should use datediff(date1, date2) to compare dates:

```
WHERE datediff(DATE_COLUMN, $dateAgo) >= 1
```

or you could use something like this:

```
WHERE DATE_COLUMN <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTHS
```

Comment: That will not do it since it is a column you want the WHERE clause on.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA the "yourSqlDatetime" should be the table column. haven't tested but it should work. Edited now

Comment: datediff is in SQL Server, NOW() INTERVAL is MYSQL.  Question to user,  do you want to include this month?  If not, it should be >= 1 AUG 2013 and <= 31 DEC 2013.  Current solution just goes to day in month.  IE - 22 AUG 2013 to now.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA mysql also has datediff http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff